# Should I specify all 4 paddings or overriding just one of them is also a good practice?

Tags: css

For a given class, I want to have the following styles:

```
stlye1 {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

But that's a lot of duplicates so I would like to just write:

```
stlye1 {
    padding: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Will this be something bad to do?

**update:**

when I see 3 values (the short hand), i'm not sure what is the last one going to apply to. 
so i came up with the second method above to make it clear which one i want to override.

**update 2:**

for a short hand method, how do you specific the followings:

```
stlye1 {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

style1 {
    padding: 0 0 10px; // now i know this one, thanks!
}



stlye2 {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

style2 {
    padding: 0 10px 0; // is this correct?
}



stlye3 {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

style3 {
    padding: 10px 0 0; // is this correct?
}



stlye4 {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

style4 {
    padding: // i have no clue.
}
```

**update 3:**

in short, style2 and 4 cannot be done in shorthand format by suppling 3 values only.
as indicated by PassKit, left and right can't be specified alone with 3 values only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your suggestion is perfectly valid, the most concise form would be:

```
stlye1 {
    padding: 0 0 10px;
}
```

This short hand format breaks down as `padding: top(0) right(0) bottom(10px);` and left defaults to the right value because a left value has not been specified.

For the 4 styles in your question, styles 1 and 3 are correct, but for styles 2 and 4, see style 5 below and the accompanying note.

For reference, the style shorthand breaks down as follows:

If there is one value, it applies to all 4 attributes, top, right, bottom and left.

```
stlye1value {
    padding: 10px;
}

/* equals */

stlye1value {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

---

If there are two values, the first value applies to top & bottom attributes and the second value to left & right

```
stlye2values {
    padding: 0 10px;
}

/* equals */

stlye2values {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

---

If there are 3 valus, the first applies to top, the second applies to left & right and the third applies to bottom.

```
stlye3values {
    padding: 0 10px 20px;
}

/* equals */

stlye3values {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

---

Specifying all 4 values sets padding in the order top, right, bottom, left (think of a clockwise circle starting at the top).

```
stlye4values {
    padding: 0 10px 20px 30px;
}

/* equals */

stlye4values {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 10px; 
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 30px;

}
```

---

**Note:** There is no way to independently specify a right or left value using shorthand without entering all 4 values or using the `padding-left` or `padding-right`.

```
style5 {
    padding-left: 10px; 
}

/* providing there are no previous padding rule for style5 equals */

style5 {
    padding: 0 0 0 10px; 
}

/* equals */

stlye5 {
    padding:0;
    padding-left:10px;
}

/* equals */

stlye5 {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 0; 
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;

}
```

Comment: i updated the question, how to handle the styles1 to 4 with the short hand method?

Comment: Revised answer to provide a breakdown of all 4 shorthands

Comment: Thanks @TomWalters - I know how frequently newcomers struggle with this, particularly with 3 values so hopefully this post will serve more than just the OP

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just use the shorthand?

```
stlye1 {
    padding: 0 0 10px; /* top (right/left) bottom */
}
```

Where it's:

```
padding: top right bottom left;
```

Comment: I would suggest for the OP's benefit explaining what happens when you use less than 4 values, it could be confusing as you only use 3 in your example. OK I'll just say it: If you omit `bottom`, it copies from `top`. If you omit `left`, it copies from `right`.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Indeed, added comment

Comment: Just use `padding-top:10px;` if the left, right and bottom have not yet been set.

Comment: Actually it depends if you're resetting your styles, if you reset padding at the top of your CSS then just using `padding-top:10px` will do the job, otherwise `padding:10px 0 0` is required

Comment: @TomWalters, please see my update 2. I think that's my real question.